# Play Widevine DRM video through ExoPlayer

Tags: android, drm, exoplayer, widevine

I'm trying to play a video protected by DRM (Widevine) through [ExoPlayer Android library](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer). Currently, we are trying to play it through the code demo of that repository.

Our video request needs a token to be added. But I don't know where to add it. We have added it in *drm_key_request_properties*:

```
{
        "name": "TEST DRM",
        "uri": "URI_OF_VIDEO",
        "drm_scheme": "widevine",
        "drm_license_url": "URL_LICENSE",
        "drm_key_request_properties": {
            "Authorization" : "CORRECT_TOKEN"
         }
}
```

But it's not working. Any idea of what can be happening?

Comment: You need to give us a little more info - what URL license are you using and are you using a proxy before the license server?